# Trying to figure out how to delete rows in table with delete all the rows in the localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-table, local-storage

So, I was trying to figure out how to delete a row in a table without deleting all the rows located in the local storage.

Here is my JS code, a table that collects data from a form.

```
var arr = new Array();
//Add data to memory
function addData() {
    getData();
    arr.push({
        contentId: document.getElementById("contentId").value,
        channel: document.getElementById("channel").value,
        follows: document.getElementById("follows").value,
        unfollows: document.getElementById("unfollows").value,
        likes: document.getElementById("likes").value,
        shares: document.getElementById("shares").value,
        views: document.getElementById("views").value,
        reaches: document.getElementById("reaches").value,
        postDate: document.getElementById("postDate").value
    });

    localStorage.setItem("localData", JSON.stringify(arr));
    showData();

}

function getData() {
    var str = localStorage.getItem("localData");
    if (str != null)
        arr = JSON.parse(str);
}

function deleteData() {
    localStorage.clear()
}

function showData() {
    getData();

    var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var x = tbl.rows.length;
    while (--x) {
        tbl.deleteRow(x);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var r = tbl.insertRow();
        var cell1 = r.insertCell();
        var cell2 = r.insertCell();
        var cell3 = r.insertCell();
        var cell4 = r.insertCell();
        var cell5 = r.insertCell();
        var cell6 = r.insertCell();
        var cell7 = r.insertCell();
        var cell8 = r.insertCell();
        var cell9 = r.insertCell();

        cell1.innerHTML = arr[i].contentId;
        cell2.innerHTML = arr[i].channel;
        cell3.innerHTML = arr[i].follows;
        cell4.innerHTML = arr[i].unfollows;
        cell5.innerHTML = arr[i].likes;
        cell6.innerHTML = arr[i].shares;
        cell7.innerHTML = arr[i].views;
        cell8.innerHTML = arr[i].reaches;
        cell9.innerHTML = arr[i].postDate;
    }

}
```

Therefore, could anyone give me a little insight into the best solution to deleting the rows in the table by using Js.

Suppose you may need my HTML code.

```
<div class="formData">
                <form onsubmit="addData(); return false;">
                    <label for="contentId">Enter ContentID:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="contentId" placeholder="ContentID" /></br>
                    <label for="follows">Enter in the social site:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="channel" placeholder="channel" /></br>
                    <label for="channel">Enter # of new followers:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="follows" placeholder="followers" /></br>
                    <label for="unfollows">Enter the # of unfollowers:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="unfollows" placeholder="Unfollowers" /></br>
                    <label for="likes">Enter the # of likes:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="likes" placeholder="Likes" /></br>
                    <label for="shares">Enter the # of shares:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="shares" placeholder="Shares" /></br>
                    <label for="views">Enter the # of views:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="views" placeholder="Views" /></br>
                    <label for="reaches">Enter the # of reaches:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="reaches" placeholder="reaches" /></br>
                    <label for="reaches">Date Posted:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="postDate" placeholder="date" /></br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add data" />
                    <input type="reset" value="clear" />
                    <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteData();" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <h3>Monthly Social Media Data</h3>
            <table id="myTable" border=1>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Content ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Channel
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Followers
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Unfollowers
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Likes
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        views
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Shares
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Reaches
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date Posted
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <script>
                showData();
            </script>
```

Comment: Please share your html, it's hard to understand what you need. How you "delete" your table row ? DOM elements are not "linked"  to your array elements

Comment: with pure javascript + html and nothing like react.js, you will probably need to re-render the table by saving a variable to the table, and saving an array variable containing all rows in the table. change "var r = tbl.insertRow()" to add to an array and then delete from the array and re-render

Comment: @bZezzz, the HTML code is now available.

Comment: Ok, so what you want to do ? Delete a row on click ? Ok, but click where ? If you want to delete a row in the DOM, you need a button or (checkbox) to specify wich one you want to  delete.

Comment: @bZezzz That makes sense thanks for the advice. I am going to try it and repost it.